# False IP conflict when using TP-Link repeater

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, repeater

I have done a little bit of troubleshooting and hope that I can give enough information in order to find some sort of a solution here. I have a tp-link wifi repeater (tl-wa855re-v4) that does not work specifically with **windows** and **iphone** users. It works perfectly fine for Linux and android users.
My setup at the moment is ISP -> tp-link running dd-wrt -> repeater -> clients. I had tried the repeater with the stock router os and it had the same issue(just to rule dd-wrt out). Before I go off and waste some more money on a new router so that I can extend my wifi coverage, I would like to check whether anyone had been able to resolve this issue before?

I have tried changing configurations on the repeater and network with no success. These are the things I have tried that failed:

1. Using the default setup of the device
2. Letting the repeater be my dhcp server (bad option)
3. Use my main router as dhcp in low ip ranges and repeater in the higher ranges.
4. Updated all firmware to the latest versions.
5. Using a static IP on the windows client.

What I have noticed is that the mac-address that the router sees when a client obtains an IP from the repeater is not the original device's mac address. Instead it creates a new hybrid mac xxx-xxx-yyy-yyy-yyy where xxx-xxx is the starting portion of the mac of the repeater and the yyy-yyy-yyy is from the device. I noticed that windows requests and IP from the DHCP, one is granted with this hybrid mac and the windows machine rejects that mac as it is a 'Duplicate'. If anybody has any pointers for me that would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is MAC Address filtering enabled in the main router? Try also the advice in comment #5 of [this post](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/88147).

Comment: I don't have MAC filtering enabled. From the main router side I have done everything that post suggested except I used the 192.168.0 subnet, because I saw this was suggested somehwere on the TP-link forum. I don't have an option to change the security on this repeater.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wa855re/) says this: "When a device connects through the extender to your router, the MAC address of the device shown on the router is translated to another MAC address. If your router’s MAC filter, wireless access control, or ACL is enabled, the devices connected to the extender cannot get an IP address from the extender and cannot access internet". Does any of it apply here? Do the phones that can't connect use any unsupported technology like 5G?

Comment: I have the same issue and no ACL or filtering on router. Any ideas?